# Adding ledger totals in multiple TDs

Tags: javascript, jquery, sum, spreadsheet

This code generates a ledger.  I narrowed it down to the minimum.  By clicking a plus sign it adds an additional row to the ledger.

I'm looking to add each total of the variable `newAmount` and locate its updated total in a TD to the right of each row. I created `newAmount.id = "mainAmount";` to create unique IDs thinking this would help.

```
var mainNumber = 0;

function addElement()
{

  //add a number for each row
  mainNumber++;


  //create each row, id each slot, and add it where it goes
  newDiv = document.createElement("div");
  newDiv.id = "main";
  newTable = document.createElement("table");
  newTable.id = "mainTable";
  newDiv.appendChild(newTable);
  newTr = document.createElement("tr")
  newTr.id = (mainNumber);
  newTr.className = "mainRow";
  newTable.appendChild(newTr);
  newAmount = document.createElement("td");
  newAmount.id = "mainAmount";
  newAmount.className = (mainNumber);
  newPlus = document.createElement("td");
  newPlus.id = "mainPlus";
  newTotalTable = document.createElement("table");
  newDiv.appendChild(newTotalTable);
  newTotalTable.id = "mainTotalTable";
  newTotalTr = document.createElement("tr");
  newTotalTable.appendChild(newTotalTr);
  newTotalTr.id = "mainTotalTr";
  newTotalTd = document.createElement("td");
  newTotalTd.id = "mainTotalTd" + (mainNumber);
  newTr.appendChild(newAmount);
  newTotalTr.appendChild(newTotalTd);

  //whats default inside of each slot
  newAmount.innerHTML = '<form name="formAmount"><textarea name="textAmount" size="25" onfocus="wait();" id="amount' + (mainNumber) + '">0</textarea>';
  newTr.appendChild(newPlus);

  //click this to add a row
  newPlus.innerHTML = '<a href="#" onclick="addElement();"><img src="images/plus.png"></a>';


  // add the newly created element and it's content into the DOM
  my_div = document.getElementById("mainAnchor");
  document.body.insertBefore(newDiv, my_div);

}

//doesn't work...trying to hover over any row and show var idName in console  
function trHover(){ 
$('tr').hover(function() {
    var idName = $('tr'+'#'+(mainNumber)).attr('id');                    
   console.log(idName);
});
}

//when you focus on amount box, this is activated, which adds attribute onblur and stars addTotal
function wait(){
var blurred = $(this).attr("onblur");
blurred = addTotal();
}

//adds total and displays it in td to the right
function addTotal(){
var y = 1;
var sum = 0;
var input;
while( ( input = document.getElementById( 'amount'+y ) ) ) {
    sum += parseInt( input.value );
    ++y;
    console.log(sum);
    $("#mainTotalTd1").text(sum);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than adding a single row, it looks like clicking the plus sign adds a div and two tables, so I'm not sure what you are going for there. I can fix the hover function, though:

```
$('tr').hover(function() {
    var idName = $(this).attr('id'); // 'this' is the element being hovered
    console.log(idName);
});
```